# Google site said You're a Robot during used Tor . what is it?

Tags: error, google

[image]

Google site said You're a Robot during used Tor . what is it? 
Google site said You're a Robot during used Tor . what is it? 
Google site said You're a Robot during used Tor . what is it? 
Google site said You're a Robot during used Tor . what is it? 
Google site said You're a Robot during used Tor . what is it? 
Google site said You're a Robot during used Tor . what is it? 
Google site said You're a Robot during used Tor . what is it?

Answer (score 0):

Send through a Tor control protocol `SIGNAL NEWNYM` - it will rebuild the circuits and you will have an exit node changed.
Or, you could press Ctrl+Shift+U in a Tor browser, that will work too.